# VHDL way to group constants together

Tags: vhdl, constants

Is it possible to group related constants together inside of packages?
What I want to do is to have generic constants but then grouped together with related constants and types. In software like Python this could be done with package inside of package or class to group constants together.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
library constants;
...
if (some_signal = constants.group_a.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE) then
    ...
end if;
```

Reader can see where the constant is coming from like here `group_a`.

Comment: Your code snippets aren't sufficiently illustrative nor are generic packages generally supported in synthesis. What have you tried and why did your attempts fail?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect more what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question well you can use records inside your package

```
package ex_pkg is

  type constants_group_1_t is record
    CONSTANT1 : integer;     
    CONSTANT2 : integer;
    CONSTANT3 : integer;
    CONSTANT4 : integer;
  end record constants_group_1_t;

constant constant_group1 : constants_group_1_t  := (
 CONSTANT1 => 1,
 CONSTANT2 => 2,
 CONSTANT3 => 3,
 CONSTANT4 => 4
);

end package;
```

then you can use it as

```
liberary work;

...

 if some_integer = work.ex_pkg.constants_group1.CONSTANT1 then

 end if;
```

so basically you declare a new record type containing all the constants that you want to use, which can be any of your chosen types, then creating a constant of the newly created type and assign for each field its value. You can then access it like "record.field" moreover you can define a record of records for as deep abstraction as you want.

Comment: This is nice! Any idea how record type behaves with synthesis?

Comment: Record types are supported by all synth tools afaik (they've been around since VHDL 87!)

Comment: they are fully supported and can be used for whatever thing you want to make. If you want to use them as ports however keep in mind that a record should have the same direction( IN, OUT or INOUT)

Comment: VHDL 2008 also supports nested packages

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. Is there example somewhere about this?